# Sort multiple arrays based on one array for TableView

Tags: ios, arrays, swift3

I have table view and three arrays which values are added to tableview cell. I would like to sort nearbyName and nearbyAddress based on nearbyDistance asc. Currently arrays looks like this:

```
nearbyName = ["Place 1", "Place2", "Place3"]
nearbyAddress = ["Address 1", "Address 2", "Address 3"]
nearbyDistance = [71.00, 50.02, 73.06]
```

I need to sort them and get result

```
nearbyName = ["Place 2", "Place1", "Place3"]
nearbyAddress = ["Address 2", "Address 1", "Address 3"]
nearbyDistance = [50.02, 71.00, 73.06]
```

In future i will get this arrays from JSON so i need to sort them automatically. Full code bellow

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class NearbyController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{


@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

let nearbyName = ["Place 1", "Place2", "Place3"]
let nearbyAddress = ["Address 1", "Address 2", "Address 3"]
let nearbyDistance = [71.00, 50.02, 73.06]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return nearbyName.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellNearby") as! NearbyCell
    cell.nearbyClubName.text = nearbyName[indexPath.row]
    cell.nearbyClubAddress.text = nearbyAddress[indexPath.row]
    cell.nearbyClubDistance.text = nearbyDistance[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
}
```

Comment: Create one single array of objects and sort/use that one.

Comment: `let wholeArray: [[String:Any]] = [["Place": "Place 1", "Address": "Address1", "Distance": 71.00], ["Place": "Place 2", "Address": "Address2", "Distance": 50.02]...]`, for the "fastest way". But creating a struct/object to describe "Place/Address/Distance" should be even better: `let wholeArray: [MyCustomObject]`.

Comment: I would suggest you work out what the JSON is going to look like first, there's no point coding assuming the data will be in the format you currently have 

Normally you would have an object for each item, the object would contain 3 properties, Name, Address and Distance and then as @Shebuka has said you can use that to sort the data.

Comment: Thanks everyone, yes i can do that, but then i have problem how to display that array data inside cell?

Comment: " then i have problem how to display that array data inside cell" Could you explain that part? If you use a custom object, then it has properties. `let myCustomObject = myWholeArray[index.row]; cell.nearbyClubName.text = myCustomObject.propertyNameWhereIsStoredTheName`?

Comment: Thanks Larme will try to do something like this :)